# Avoid writing username in User Access Control screen

Tags: windows-10, uac

I use Windows 10 and it frequently pops up this dialogue:
"Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your PC?"

It is just fine asking me this, but I am annoyed at writing my username every time. Writing my password is fine (maybe), but I prefer selecting my username from a dropdown list, or using my current username as a default value there.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: "but I prefer selecting my username from a dropdown list" - This functionality does not exist in Windows at this time.  "or using my current username as a default value there." - This should already be the case if the account is in Administrator user group

Comment: In previous versions of Windows (eg. 7), there was no need of writing down the username, so may be there is a way to return the old way. BTW I am an administrator of the PC.